# Angular js - increment months in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter

I would like to increment the month like this:

```
 var date = new Date();
    $scope.month = $filter('date')(date, 'MMMM');
    $scope.nextMonth = function () {                
     //set next month
     $scope.month = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.month).getMonth()+1, 'MMMM');
    };
```

how can i achieve this?

So for example if

`$scope.month = "November";`

**$scope.nextMonth();** should set `$scope.month  = "December";`

> NB: I cant use any external library for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular doesn't have anything built in to do this, so you need to use the native Javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) methods.

If you're doing a lot of work with dates, however, I would strongly recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

This would make the above incredibly simple:

```
$scope.month = moment().format('MMMM')
$scope.nextMonth = function(){
    $scope.month.add(1, 'month');
}
```

EDIT:

Without using an external library you can still do it, and you pretty much have the code:

```
$scope.nextMonth = function(){
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  return $scope.month = $filter('date')(date, 'MMMM');
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to say im not using moment.js and i cant use it :P

Comment: nope you are setting +1 month based on current month and not based on scope.month :P

Comment: i need to increment the scope.month not the current month everytime ;)

Comment: Well, you are setting `$scope.month` to a string, so either convert it back into a date based on that, then add a month, or save both a string (`$scope.month.name`) and a date object (`$scope.month.date`) and work from there...

Comment: Also, unless you are changing `$scope.month` elsewhere, `date` **is** `$scope.month`. This line `var date = new Date();` only runs once.

Answer (score 1):

works only for months

```
$scope.nextMonth = function(){
  var index = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH.indexOf($scope.month);
  $scope.month = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH[index == 11 ? 0 : index + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.date = (new Date((new Date()).setMonth((new Date()).getMonth()
 + 1))).toLocaleDateString('fr-FR')
```